# XAMPP 5.6.11-0 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 Apache Web Server won't run

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, localhost, server

In the XAMPP Application Manager both the "MySQL Database" and "ProFTPD" apps have a status of "Running". The "Apache Web Server" app has a status of "Stopped".

If you click on the Applications Log in XAMPP Applications Manager, it says:

***Starting Apache Web Srver… /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started***

I did a config test in the Terminal using "sudo apachectl configtest". The Terminal came back with the following:

***httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Jennifers-iMac-2.local for ServerName
Syntax OK***

Web Sharing is turned on in System Preferences. Web Sharing also has its own folder in the System Library.

There is a "Sites" folder under my User's directory in which I have placed some WordPress plugins folders. I will be attempting to utilize these once Apache gets running. I'm not sure they are in the correct folder, as I added them there prior to installing XAMPP.

The XAMPP Application Manager has Apache Web Server at Port 80.

XAMPP is installed in the Applications folder.

I am not a developer, so I am not real comfortable with messing with the Terminal. But if I have to, I will.

Any suggestions on how I can get Apache to run? I've been trying to set up a localhost server for 3 days now with zero success….

Comment: so what exactly is the problem? "won't run" doesn't exactly tell us much. done any basic debugging, like `ps -aux|grep httpd` to see if it really IS running? checked logs for errors/details?

Comment: Well, the XAMPP Application Manager Window lists the "Status" of Apache as "Stopped", and the "MySQL Database" and "ProFTPD" apps are listed with a "Status" of "Running", so that is why I describe it as "Not Running."

Comment: then check the `ps` output to confirm that there's no apache processes, then start digging in the logs to see what (if anything) is getting logged when it shuts down (or crashes).

Comment: I should also mention that when I type in my browser "http://localhost" it brings up the html test file located in Macintosh HD/Library/Web Server/Documents.

Comment: then apache is running... and your problem is that you haven't configured apache to look in this wordpress directory instead of its default document root.

Comment: I'm guessing I use Terminal to check the "ps" output? Sorry, I'm not a developer, just person trying to get a local test server up and functional. I apologize for the lack of knowledge!

Comment: yah. `ps` is a unix command-line app. you could also check the mac's activity monitor and see if apache's showing up there. but the fact that you get the default page means it IS running.

Comment: How do I configure Apache to the proper Wordpress directory?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Comment: I will start a new discussion asking how to configure Apache to recognize the Wordpress directory.